# Covering a compact set by neighborhoods without too much overlap

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let X be a compact metric space, and $\varepsilon$ positive real number. Show that there exists a subset $S\subseteq X$ such that the sets $N_\varepsilon(s)$ for $s\in S$ form a cover of $X$, and such that the distance between any two points of $S$ is $\geq\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$

This is the hint that I was given: First find a finite set $T$ such that the sets $N_\frac{\varepsilon}{2}(s)$ for $s\in T$ form a cover of $X$. Then get a subset $S\subseteq T$ such that the distance between any two points of $S$ is $\geq\frac{\varepsilon}{2},$ but such that no larger subset of $T$ has that property. Then show that the $N_\varepsilon(s)$ for $s\in S$ must cover $X$.

How do I go about finding this finite set $T?$

Comment: The collection of sets of the form $N_{\epsilon/2}(s)$ for $s \in X$ is an open cover of $X$, and $X$ is compact, therefore there's a finite subcover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First take the collection $N_{\varepsilon/2}(s)$ for all $s \in X$. Let $T=\{t_1, .., t_n\}$ be a finite subcover which exists by compactness of $X$. Now construct $S \subset T$ by defining $t_1 \in S$ and $t_i$ in $S$ if and only if the distance of $t_i$ to all $t_j$ with $j < i$ is greater than $\varepsilon/2$.

Claim: the $\varepsilon$-balls around $S$ also cover $X$. Suppose to the contrary that there exists $x \in X$ not covered. Then there exists $t_i \in T$ such that $x \in N_{\varepsilon/2}(t_i)$ because $T$ defines a cover. Now if $t_i \in S$ then $x$ would be covered. If $t_i \notin S$ there must be a $t_j \in S$ with distance $t_i, t_j$ smaller than $\varepsilon/2$ but then $x \in N_{\varepsilon}(t_j)$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal{U}=\{N_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}(x): x \in X\}$ is an open cover of $X$ (open balls are open in the metric topology and every $x \in X$ is covered by the ball with $x$ as its centre), so the **definition** of compactness tells us that there is a finite subset $T$ of $X$ such that $\{N_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}(x): x \in T\}$ is a cover of $X$ too.

Comment: This doesn't guarantee that the sets in $T$ have distance greater than $\varepsilon/2$.

Comment: @quarague that’s the step finding a subset $S$ of $T$which is now doable by finiteness.